# Manual Install of GWT 2.1.0 in Eclipse Helios 3.6.1

Tags: eclipse, gwt, installation

I am behind an intranet that does not have access to the download sites.  Assuming I have access to all of the correct zip and jar files.  What are the step by step instructions to get Eclipse to the point where I can go to Windows -> Preferences and see the Google entry?

---

1)  I don't have access to the http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started.html site because I am on a closed network.
2)  I tried using the dropins folder and when I re-open Eclipse and go to Windows->Preferences "Google" isn't listed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The official zip-file installation instructions are at http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip.html

This uses the Eclipse [dropins mechanism](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started#Dropins), which helps Eclipse to pick up the new plugins in a clean way, quote:

> ... the dropins folder can be used much like the plugins directory was used in the past. A subtle twist on old behavior here is that plug-ins and features added to the dropins folder are properly installed into the system rather than being forced in.

**Note:**

Make sure, that you extract the zip file into the correct destination. It can easily happen, that it gets extracted e.g. into some subdirectory - so please check twice. You should have the following structure:

```
eclipse (this is your Eclipse installation folder)
   dropins
      eclipse (this is the directory created by extracting the zip file)
         features
            com.google.*
         plugins
            com.google.*
  features
     (your already installed features)
  plugins
     (your already installed plugins)
  ...
```

Then (re-)start Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks Chris...I've done this and when I check the installed plugins...I see "google Eclipse Platform Plugin" and "Google Eclipse Shared Platform Plugin" in the list of installed plugins. What I dont' see that I was expecting is when I open Eclipse and go to Window-->Preferences...I expected to see Google in the list and it isn't. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Just install the plugin from here and you are set to go.
http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

If you get a correct zip file for plugin, you will see "plugins" and "features" as soon as you open the zip file.

If your eclipse is in a location "c:\eclipse", extract the zip file into "c:\eclipse". The files will go into the corresponding folders.

Answer (score 0):

Drop them in the plugins folder